# STR_TO_DATE Conversion in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made this query which select the date in column,
 now i want to get the year only from selected date .

```
SELECT column_Name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = STR_TO_DATE( '00/00/0000', '%m/%d/%Y' )
```

Please solve this problem.

Comment: your question is unclear, what is the problem??

Comment: Agreed.  The question is very unclear.  Do you mean that you want to pull the Year out of the DATETIME field?

Comment: I made this query which selects whole date in column, now i want to select year only. SELECT column_Name FROM table_name WHERE column_name = STR_TO_DATE( '00/00/0000', '%m/%d/%Y').

Comment: Use the `YEAR` function which Ramesh has in his `WHERE` clause to only pull back the year from a `DATE` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ans of this unclear question should be

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE( '00/00/0000', '%m/%d/%Y' )) as date from table_name
```

you should get help fron it

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE YEAR(column_name) = 2012
```

Comment: +1 - One small thing, the '2012' doesn't need to be (and shouldn't be) in quotes.